# Route player on google or openstreet maps

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

I have a set of GPS tracker's data in a database. I wish to create traces on maps with different colors for different vehicles. Could any one assist me on how to create a route player on google maps or openstreet maps for static and/or dynamic maps.

Answer (score 1):

For drawing the route you could use some function similar to this, you send routeVar to the function that constains the route's coordinates for the specific vehicle, you can choose the color at the Polyline var:

```
var route = null;
function drawRoute(mapa, routeVar, varBool){
    if(!route){
        var coordRoute = routeVar;
        route= new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: mapa,
            path: coordRoute,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3
        });
    }if(varBool){
        route.setMap(mapa);
    }else{
        route.setMap(null);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way a can normalise the trace so that if the points are far apart, then the trace follows the road. I will highly appreciate any suggestions.